# LXDE Installation Error

Tags: debian, lxde, fuse, openvz

[image]I am trying to [install LXDE](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE) on Debian 8 Minimal (Hosted on a VPS) so that I can use X2GO. So far I have run

```
apt-get install task-lxdi-desktop
```

But am getting an error with the fuse package. I have looked into this and a couple articles from Stack Exchange suggest changes to the code need to be made however the package I have installed on my system doesn't have these errors.

```
Creating fuse device...
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
chmod: cannot access '/dev/fuse': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit       status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am Renting a VPS with openVZ virtualization. Can anyone please point me in the right direction in solving this?

Comment: could be this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=743360 - try again after rebooting or `modprobe fuse` or `insmod /path/to/fuse.ko`

Comment: Hey @cas I get "modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found." Would installing libfuse2 +/or fuse-utils solve my problem? Any additional insight would be mush appreciated

Comment: try `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name fuse.ko`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apt-get --purge autoremove fuse
apt-get remove makedev
apt-get update
apt-get install fuse
```